# Liferay with MarkLogic XDBC database integration

Tags: java, database, liferay, marklogic, marklogic-8

I'm a newbie programmer with Liferay and Marklogic.
I'm trying to connect the MarkLogic using these guides

https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Database+Portal+Properties

but to no avail. May I know what kind of database MarkLogic is? and how do I implement the connection?

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried already and where are you stuck? Share some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marklogic is a NoSQL database and [not supported](https://www.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix) as a backend for Liferay - which you seem to configure it for. If you write your own application on top of Liferay, you are able to connect to any database you like - including Marklogic. It's just not for Liferay's own data.

If you're asking how to build your own application on top of it: That's way too broad for a simple question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you Olaf! do you know any good tutorials for creating such?

Comment: Good samples for liferay are on http://dev.liferay.com - marklogic probably has samples for an app using it. You'll have to adopt the UI side (Liferay) to it then